# JsTree Check box select all fields with corresponding parent

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I am using JsTree for filter option.

Now while selecting the parent node it gives the all the children and sub child in a single array.

So I am not able to identify which child belongs to which parent.

Here is my sample code,

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false
        },
            "plugins": ["checkbox"],
            'core' : {
                'data' :  [
  {
    "id": "ALL",
    "text": "ALL",
    "children": [

      {
        "id": "TWO",
        "text": "TWO",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "C2",
            "text": "C2",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "S2",
                "text": "S2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
            }
    });

    var selected_items = {}

    $("#tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
               console.log(data.node);
                         });
});
```

It gives children as,

```
[
  "S2",
  "C2",
  "S3",
  "T3",
  "C3",
  "D3",
  "ONE",
  "TWO",
  "THREE"
]
```

So how can I identify child and their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the selected nodeId to get the node back from the tree giving you all of the child and parent relationships

```
$("#tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {    
        var jsonOfSelectedNode = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_json(data.node, {flat:true})
        // debug here and view 
});
```

*jsonOfSelectedNode* will give you all of the required parent child data